# Confusion about vcxproject paths in popular software

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have download a software maintained by Carnegie Mellon:
https://github.com/festvox/flite

There is a sln, and in this solution, there's a vcxproj contained.
This project file states the following path for a ".c" file:

```
<ClCompile Include="..\..\lang\cmu_grapheme_lang\cmu_grapheme_lang.c" />
```

However, the actual folder structure on disk looks like this:

[image]

In my opinion, the location should be stated like this in the vcproj file instead:

```
<ClCompile Include="lang\cmu_grapheme_lang\cmu_grapheme_lang.c" />
```

I also think so because when I double-click the file in VS2017, it tells me that a part of the path couldn't be found:

[image]

I think a project which is so actively maintained would have this set up correctly, so I wonder if there's any option in VS2017 that I might perhaps just not have set right.

Thank you for any clarification on this problem.

Comment: That project doesn't look that active to me. The readme recommends compiling with cygwin, mingw, or Windows subsystem for linux. Given that the suo file is checked in and 2/3 of the projects do not exist I'd guess this is either not meant to compile out of the box for Visual Studio, or the developer handling that isn't doing a very good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - that file reference looks wrong. My best guess is that the developer indeed has that `lang\cmu_grapheme_lang` directory in the specified location and just neglected to make sure that the project on GitHub has valid settings (one of those "hey, this builds on my system so it *must* be correct" fiascos).

In your particular case: to properly build either fix the project file or copy the `lang\cmu_grapheme_lang` directory into expected location.

Comment: Indeed! I do it so often that it didn't even occur to me to specify that. But you are right - it is worth mentioning that those project files are best "fixed" with a regular text editor :)